# Leibniz Formula Proof (Rule of Sarrus)

Tags: matrices

Can anyone prove this:

$\det(M) =\begin{vmatrix} a_{11} & a_{12} & a_{13} \\  a_{21} & a_{22} & a_{23} \\ a_{31} & a_{32} & a_{33} \end{vmatrix} = a_{11}a_{22}a_{33}+a_{12}a_{23}a_{31}+a_{13}a_{21}a_{32}-a_{31}a_{22}a_{13}-a_{32}a_{23}a_{11}-a_{33}a_{21}a_{12}$

Comment: This is just [Leibniz formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_formula_for_determinants) for $n=3$. What is your definition of determinant?

Comment: Oh I didn't realise, I basically want to prove the equation

Answer (score 5):

You can just calculate :

$$\det(M)=\begin{vmatrix} a_{11} & a_{12} & a_{13} \\  a_{21} & a_{22} & a_{23} \\ a_{31} & a_{32} & a_{33} \end{vmatrix}=a_{11}\times\begin{vmatrix}a_{22}&a_{23}\\a_{32}&a_{33}\end{vmatrix}-a_{12}\times\begin{vmatrix}a_{21}&a_{23}\\a_{31}&a_{33}\end{vmatrix}+a_{13}\times\begin{vmatrix}a_{21}&a_{22}\\a_{31}&a_{32}\end{vmatrix}$$ and as $\begin{vmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{vmatrix}=ad-bc$ you get your result.

Answer (score 3):

[Sarrus Rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_Sarrus) is the graphical method, extending the matrix and then using the diagonals.

More useful is to learn the Laplace development of a determinant:

$$
\text{det}(A)
= \sum_j (-1)^{i+j} a_{ij} \, \text{det}(S_{ij})
= \sum_i (-1)^{i+j} a_{ij} \, \text{det}(S_{ij})
$$
where $S_{ij}$ is the matrix with row $i$ and column $j$ removed,
because it reduces the dimension of the determinants involved by one each time one uses it, until one hits the easy to calculate 2-determinants (or 1-determinants).